# Weka - binary classification giving polarized/biased results

Tags: classification, weka

Let me say, first up, that I'm a WEKA newbie.

I'm using WEKA for a binary classification problem where certain metrics are being used to get a yes/no answer for the instances.

To exemplify the issue, here's the confusion matrix I got for a set with 288 instances, with 190 'yes' and 98 'no' values using BayesNet:

```
  a   b   <-- classified as
190   0 |   a = yes
 98   0 |   b = no
```

This absolute separation is the case with some other classifiers as well, but not with all of them. That said, even if classifiers don't have values polarized to such a degree, they do have a definite bias for the predominant class. For example, here's the result with RandomForest:

```
  a   b   <-- classified as
164  34 |   a = yes
 62  28 |   b = no
```

I'm pretty certain I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: So what's your question? The predominant class is almost twice as large as the other one, so yes, all the classifiers would (and should) have a bias for it.

Comment: Is the result indicating a total bias for the predominant class normal, then? With BayesNet, for example, I ALWAYS get this totally one sided result with a Kappa statistic value of 0. No matter what data set or metrics I use. Is this how this should work?
The results with RandomForest are acceptable, I concede, but BayesNet stumps me.

Comment: Hard to say what's going on without the full data. The features may not achieve good separation (at least as far as BayesNet is concerned). I guess the short answer is don't use BayesNet for this particular task :)

Comment: That's the way I'm going - there's a precedent in this field to use classifiers like NaiveBayes and BayesNet for *similar* end purposes, though I'm taking a basically different approach here, which might very well mean that use of these classifiers isn't the way to go.

Comment: If you'd like to reduce the bias, you can tweak the error-weights (e.g. via CostSensitiveClassifier) to compensate for the uneven class distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Originally, I thought that BayesNet is the problem. But now I think it is your data.

As it was already pointed out in the comments, I thought the problem is with the unbalanced classes. Most classifiers optimize for accuracy, which in your case is `(190 + 0) / 288 = 0.66` for the BayesNet and `(164 + 28) / 288 = 0.67` for the RandomForest.

As you can see, the difference is not that big, but the solution found by RandomForest is marginally better. It looks "better" because it doesn't put everything in the same class, but I really doubt it is statistically significant.

Like Lars Kotthoff mentioned, it is hard to say. I'd also guess that the features are just not good enough for a better separation.

In addition to trying other classifiers you should reconsider your performance measure. *Accuracy* is only good if you have approximately the same number of instances for each class. In other cases, [MCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient) or [AUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_Under_the_Curve) are good choices (but AUC won't work with LibSVM in WEKA due to incompatible implementations).

The MCC for your examples would be 0 for the BayesNet and

```
  ((164*28) - (62*34)) / sqrt((164+62)*(34+28)*(164+34)*(62+28))
= (4592 - 2108) / sqrt(226 * 62 * 198 * 90)
= 2484 / sqrt(249693840)
= 0,15719823927071640929
```

for RandomForest. So RandomForest shows a slightly better result, but not that much better.

Hard to tell without seeing your data, but they are probably not well separable.

Comment: The field that I'm working in generally considers an accuracy value of 70% to be pretty good. In any case, though, I too am starting to think that these measures aren't really as accurate as one would want.

Also, I think the denominator in your calculation of MCC should be sqrt(249693840) and not 249693840. If so, MCC comes to around 0.157. Not great, obviously, but somewhat less discouraging than 0.00001, I suppose ;)

Comment: Just to clarify - if I forget about the accuracy (or the lack thereof) for a minute, there is no silly mistake that I'm making that is causing the classifiers to give such results, right? 

Low accuracy is something I can look into, but I hope I'm not making some basic error which is causing anomalous classifier behavior.

Comment: @ShredOn Well, there is nothing that would come instantly to my mind, but it's not impossible that there could be an error. Can you include the (hopefully short) source code that produced your results in your question?

Comment: I can tell you approximately what I'm doing. I'm parsing a text file which has various segments and finding whether a particular word pattern occurs in a given segment and labelling that segment as yes/no based on this. A separate processing of the same text file yields a graph containing the segments as nodes interconnected on the basis some other criteria. I'm creating an .arff file which contains the graph metrics for each node (i.e. a segment) and whether this segment is yes/no, then classifying using the graph metrics.

Comment: @ShredOn Phew, that's a bit complicated. But complexity can lead to errors, so all I can tell you is to check the algorithm again, with which you create your features.

Comment: Will do. I guess there's no glaring, obvious error in my use or understanding of WEKA, which was what I was worried about. In all probability, these particualar metrics aren't all that great for the final purpose. Thanks for the help.