# Weka: Too much optimistic results

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, svm, evaluation

I am using Weka to do some classification tasks. As I am using SVM, the False Positive Rate is 0. This is very much optimistic to me for the classification task. Also, in some of my previous experiments, I have seen optimistic results like precision and recall scores as 100. My question is- if you have such optimistic results, what are the possibilities for which this is happening? And what are the remedies?

Comment: False positive rate of 0 might mean that you're always, or almost always, predicting negative; what's the false negative rate? Precision and recall both 100 at the same time means either your problem is quite easy or (maybe more likely) there's a bug in your data handling; maybe your code has the labels wrong, or something.

Comment: Thanks @Dougal. The false negative rate is quite there but the true negative rate is 1. This means that SVM is finding everything as negative. The problem is not quite easy as I have about 3000 instances. However, I just have 3 variables (including class feature). The problem is a binary classification problem (spam detection). If I add other features, then this optimistic result is not there.

Comment: Possibly, we are facing the same problem but in different ways- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479779/weka-binary-classification-giving-polarized-biased-results

Comment: Well, if your SVM is getting all negative results that explains why you're seeing 0 false positives. Try normalizing the features if you haven't already, and you could try setting class rates. What's the actual portion of positives in your training / test sets? You could also try playing with class weights to make a false positive not as bad as a false negative. That said, two features is very few for something like spam detection, and it's not super surprising you're seeing it just predict the mean if there isn't much signal to extract.

Comment: Also try using different kernels, and make sure you're tuning the kernel bandwidth and SVM margin penalty term.

Comment: **Overfitting** and a flawed evaluation (wrt. train/test split)?